# Encryption issue in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-phone-8, parse-platform

I'm designing a Windows Phone 8 app where I need to save certain credentials and message backups as a Parse object. So, while I'm taking data from the user end I want to preserve privacy of the clients. So, why not encrypt it. But then again I need to decrypt it back on client side. Say, there's a message "I'll be late". So, I want it to be encrypted to say "@##%&**))^^^__673asdh" and saved in backend which makes absolute no sense to me. Again this encrypted message is read back to the front end client as and when required as the original message that he stored. Please suggest a good library. is AES a good option? Sorry for the question. I'm basically a noob in cryptography! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are noob in cryptography - do not use encrytion/decryption primitives. Encryption/decryption method is only a part where proper use of the method is very important too. Try to find some crypto library that will do the work for you. At start you can read about [Crypto++](http://developer.nokia.com/blogs/community/using-crypto-library-with-windows-phone-8-featured-article-windows-phone) library and [BounceCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/), inspect the exmaples in this libraries.